# image keeps disappearing when making my page/view smaller

Tags: html, css, responsive-images

My background image keeps disappearing whenever the screen gets smaller. I want to make it responsive.

This is what I have for my CSS code:

```
#heading {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background: url('#someimage') top center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size:cover; 
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

This what I have for my HTML Code

```
<header>
    <div class="jumbotron text-center" id="heading">
        <div class="container intro-text">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="main col-xs-12">
            <h1>Name</h1>
            <hr class="separator separator-light">
            <h2 class="subhead">Name <i class="fa fa-laptop"></i> Name <i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o"></i> Name</h2>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: add `class="img-responsive" ` in your .jumbotron section

Comment: it still is disappearing when the screen gets smaller after adding this

Comment: Your code works good for me.

Comment: I also have a nav bar at the top before the image, I tried the code like it is with a random image and it works without the navbar. There must be something wrong with my navbar code that is interfering with the image

Comment: I took out "nav-bar-fixed-top" and it works now!

Answer (score 1):

Please try to add `"background-size:100%"` instead of `"background-size:cover"`